# How can I decide the start of outliers to modify their values?

Tags: distributions, outliers, resampling

[image: Image size distribution]

I have this figure above showing the distribution of my images sizes. As you can see the distribution is right skewed. In order to make the data reasonable I have to cut out in a certain range (ex. 500 and above) which we can call them outliers in this case and modify (re-sample) them by re-scaling their size to fit in the middle of the distribution instead of throwing them out of the dataset.

I can't decide on the cut of the outliers. Is there any technical method to decide in this matter?

Comment: You not only have outliers  but possibly inliers as well (two many central values)

Comment: @IrishStat I don't have problem with these inliers since they are all in the range 25 to 167 I can find a middle range between them in case I want to unify their size or define Quantiles.  But looking at range upto 3000 is a big problem in image re-scaling.

Comment: In what sense, exactly, would removing *any* of the larger image sizes make these data more "reasonable"?  (The concept of "too many central values" scarcely merits any comment beyond suggesting that you ignore it.)

Comment: These too many central values gives an indication to decide on a unified size if I'm not wrong. Specially the highest central values range in a very close range. So images won't be highly distorted by rescaling them. My concern is about these large images sizes. Scaling down is not a big issue but up might create a problem. By defining a central value on a normal distribution i can define that unified size. Thanks.

Comment: Following @Feras "There too many central values"

Comment: Without knowing anything about the images, do you have a theoretical reason for being able to cut out some images (e.g. they came from the same source, they were shot on a particular type of camera, they are of a certain size). Removing these might help more than using an arbitrary cutoff.

Comment: They are collected randomly from the internet and cleaned by human then cropped by some methods. the images vary in size distribution which is not that problem for small range. even having very high central value is positive thing so I could use this value to re-scale the rest to this size. my concern is about the outliers, starting from which range I should make the cut and re-sample(down scale) them into the high concentration images sizes.